# how to deal with "app has stopped"problem in android studio

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

My app is kind of a calculator, when I hit the calculate button, the app stops and shows "`app has stopped open again`" . I'm calling the calculation code from eclipse work-space.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.ctc, PID:
>   22378 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "any"
>
> at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
>   at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110) at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539) at
>   com.example.ctc.Walls1$2.onClick(Walls1.java:103) at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>   Application terminated.`

Comment: Eclipse and Android Studio are completely different things - which one are you using?

Comment: @Harish Kumar R, i think may be you are trying to perform mathematical operation on string's, so first parse them to integer type. please show us your code. thank you

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "any"` means that you can't parse a number from the string "any". But we can't fix your code without seeing it.

Comment: @greg-449 Im using eclipse as a server that contains the calculation code for the app in android.However i got the output,i was using string for one of the inputs which should have a integer for calculation

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Thanks for the answer,i was using a string input in the place of double,now my app is working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using an `EditText` to get the input and although you expect numbers, the retrieved data is in the form of `String`. In fact, you have to use `editTextName.getText().toString()` to further process it. If you are sure that the incoming input will be numbers, you may convert them (as, I think, you already try to) to numbers to make numerical calculations. You may try showing a numerical-only keyboard to the users so that they avoid posting other types of `char`s, but then, the processing differs a little.

Without posting your actual source code, not much can be said.

> App stopped working

is not a specific error and it may be caused by any run-time problem in your code. Thus, asking for "fix" is not the way to ask for help.

Hope above info helps.